# While downloding excel \n and \t is not working

Tags: php

i wrote code for downloading excel file. it that i an giving header and data. but my header is not getting seperated in tabs. it is cuming in one tab(in one column) only. pls refer m code.

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);

    $header = "Sr No. \t Team Member Name \t Profile Name \t Email Id. \t Guys Count \tGirls Count \tNo.paid guys \tNo.paid girls \t Guest Count";


    while ($row_gl = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {

            $sr_no = str_replace('"', '""', $count);
            $sr_no = '"' . $sr_no . '"' . "\t";
            $line .= $sr_no;

            if (empty($row_gl['ds_comments']))
            {
                $gl_count = str_replace('"', '""', "NA");
                $gl_count = '"' . $gl_count . '"' . "\n";
                $line .= $gl_count;
            }
            else
            {
                $gl_count = str_replace('"', '""', $row_gl['ds_comments']);
                $gl_count = '"' . $gl_count . '"' . "\n";
                $line .= $gl_count;
            }

            $count++;    
    }
    $name = date('d-m-y');
    //header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");

    header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel;name='excel'");

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name. ".xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    // Output data
    echo $header . "\n\n" . $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of separating by comma instead and creating a CSV?

Personally I'd use one of the existing PHP to Excel libraries or a CSV for something like this.

Comment: i separated with \t and next line \n. i am not creating csv. i want to create excel file.